# Why 64-bit OS on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, operating-systems, 64-bit

Considering that:

1. Raspberry Pi 4 maximum RAM is 4Gb and so its memory is completely addressable by a 32bit OS
2. all the code available for Raspberry is a 32bit code

are there any meaningful and reasonable advantages to run a 64bit OS?

This a background question behind all the recurring searches for a 64Bit OS per Raspberry Pi 4 and even for Raspberry Pi 3.

***Update***

If there aren't any reasonable advantages to run a 64bit OS on a Raspberry Pi 4 due to its limits in RAM size why compile, offer and search for a 64bit OS? Would it be even worse than run a 32bit OS?

Comment: The default Raspbian Buster for Pi4B is still 32-bit. There's nothing that will force you to go to a 64-bit OS.

Comment: [This topic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=247959) has lots of useful information on the subject.

Comment: For memory mapping the sea of additional virtual addresses is extremely helpful.

Comment: Although the duplicate is not specifically about the Pi 4 and predates it, the answer here is the same regardless of model.  Then "Why compile, offer and search for a 64bit OS?" is too much of a subjective and opinion based question, by which I mean different people may have different reasons, all of them equally valid.  That's fine for a discussion style forum, but this is not.  If you have a concrete context (eg., "I use my Pi for _____, would I benefit from a 64-bit OS?"), then that's a specific question with a reasonably objective singular answer.

Comment: My idea was to objectively and technically know whether it is better to use a 32bit instead of a 64bit OS on Raspberry Pi 4 but never mind.